# Does the Livecode combobox support multiple column

Tags: livecode

I have linked a livecode application to a relational database. I want to use a combobox to display values related to an ID. I other program such as msaccess this is done by having combobox with 2 columns. The first is linked to the ID and set to 0 width and the second displays the related value. Is that possible in livecode?

I have a text field and a list field and I managed to get it working using the following code  on rawkeyup

```
global strHilitedLine,strTempHilitedLine,booAfterReturn,booFirstKeyUp

on keyup -- when your press a character key

   TempHilited


end keyup

on returninfield --when user press return key on keyboard

 --accept the temporary hilite
   put the hilitedLine of field "lstfood" into strHilitedLine

   put empty into strTempHilitedLine

   --set booFirstKeyUp to true so that the keyup command will know that
   -- the next keyup is the first after clicking the enter/return key
   put "True" into booFirstKeyUp
   --clear field txtfood
   put empty into fld "txtFood"

end returninfield

on enterkey --when user press enter key on mobile(code same as on returninfield)

   set the hilitedLine of field "lstfood" to strTempHilitedLine
   put the hilitedLine of field "lstfood" into strHilitedLine
   put empty into strTempHilitedLine
   put "True" into booFirstKeyUp
   put empty into fld "txtFood"

end enterkey

on TempHilited

   if booFirstKeyUp="True" then 
   --store the value of hilitedline if this is the first keyup after
   -- clicking enter(see on enterkey)

      put the hilitedLine of field "lstfood" into strHilitedLine
      put "False" into booFirstKeyUp

   end if

   --set hilitedlines to the hilitedlines just after clicking enter
   set the hilitedLine of field "lstfood" to strHilitedLine

   -- cleartemporary hilitedlines from previous keyup
   put empty into strTempHilitedLine

   -- create array from field lstFood and find if the text in txtFood
   -- appears at the start of any item in the array
   put field "lstfood" into arrFood
   filter lines of arrFood with regex pattern "^" & me into strLineText

   --create new value to temporarily hilite
   if the length of strHilitedLine>0 and the length of strLineText>0 then

      put  strHilitedLine &  "," & lineoffset (strLineText ,field
     "lstfood")    after strTempHilitedLine

   else if   the length of strHilitedLine>0 then

      put  strHilitedLine  into strTempHilitedLine

   else if  the length of strLineText>0 then

      put  lineoffset (strLineText ,field "lstfood")  into strTempHilitedLine

   end if

 --set temporay hilite
   set the hilitedLine of field "lstfood" to strTempHilitedLine
   put the length of me into mylength

  --Select the part of txtFood that user did to type so that it is overwritten on the next keyup
   put strlinetext into field "txtFood"
   select char mylength +1 to the length of me of field "txtFood"

End TempHilited
```

As you can see it is a long convoluted code. Happy to hear if you have a more
    -- efficient way of achieving the same.

You mentioned "Store the data in a custom property, filter to include relevant lines, put the remaining data into the field" and I believe you were alluding to another method of doing it but I have not really work out how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, menu buttons don't allow for multiple columns in LiveCode. However, it is possible to make your own combobox, e.g. by using a stack panel for a menu and adding two fields to that stack. Use the properties inspector of a menu button to assign a stack as a stack panel.

I made such a stack panel, with only one column, quite some time ago:

[image]

It would be easy to make this a two-column menu: just make the field half as wide, add another field and update the hilitedLine of the field that doesn't have focus when the hilitedLine of the focused field changes. This example isn't a real stack panel, but it works pretty much the same. I open the stack hidden as a palette, set the size and location, and show it making sure that it has focus.

(The picture is from my own website; the library is in an area available to donors only).

Comment: Hi Mark, I am a bit lost.I see a list field and text field in the picture. It seems that the list field gets hilited as you type in the text field. How do you get it to do this. Also how much donation is required to access your library

Comment: @Sheila I'd rather be a moderate with self-promotion, so perhaps you can contact me through another channel and ask me again? The list field is in a different stack, which is opened as a palette. The field contains a script, which simply filters and displays the list. The hilite is done with either mouse or arrow keys.

Comment: Hi Mark, I am slowly working if out. I have a text field and a list field and using the following code I can find the line in the list field that contain the string in the text field. I can later use the lineoffset value to hilite the relevate row.
`on rawkeyup
 
   answer lineoffset (me,field "lstfood")
   
end rawkeyup`

But it's picking any line in the list field that contain the string from the text field. I only want to select the ones from the list that start with the string in the text field. I will contact you later re your website. By the way my name is Sheils (Male). Cheers

Comment: Sheils, you might want to add your preliminary solution to the question. That makes it easier to understand and if I update my answer it would still make sense,

Comment: The answer command may change focus and selections and thus cause unexpected results. Don't use it in this case. Check out the filter command in the LC dictionary. Store the datain a custom property, filter to include relevant lines, put the remaining data into the field.

Comment: Mark, I have added my temporary solution. But after looking at it is seems that I have strayed away from my original question. Any suggestions